# Retrieve external URL of media file

Tags: c1-cms

I have a page data folder with a property "Image", which is a reference to a Media file in the Composite C1 backend.

I now want to retrieve the data in my asp.net user control, but all I get when I access the "Image" Property of my PageDataFolder Type, is a string with the following format:

> mediaarchive:b5354eba-3f69-4885-9eba-74576dff372d

I am not sure how to get the external image url from that. Is there an API function I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a url like

~/media(**{MediaKey}**)

example: "~/media(mediaarchive:b5354eba-3f69-4885-9eba-74576dff372d)"

Once C1 page is rendered, it will be replaced with the following SEO friendly url:

/media/**{Path to your image in media archive}**)

example: "/media/5611182f-6462-4b80-a051-3c3b9bb3276d/References/Screenshots/Olympiacos/1_png"

Note that you can specify image resing/cropping options via query string.
http://docs.composite.net/Getting-started/Configuration/Resizing-Images

If you, for some reason cannot rely on the C1 page rendering logic, you can build a public media url with the following code:

```
protected string GetMediaUrl(string mediaPath)
{
    string[] parts = mediaPath.Split(new[] { ':' });

    string mediaStore = parts[0];
    Guid mediaId = new Guid(parts[1]);

    string mediaUrl = MediaUrls.BuildUrl(new MediaUrlData { MediaStore = mediaStore, MediaId = mediaId, QueryParameters = new NameValueCollection() },
                                         UrlKind.Public);

    // Temporary fix, allows media player to receive a nice url with an extension
    return mediaUrl.Replace("_jpg", ".jpg").Replace("_mov", ".mov").Replace("_m4v", ".m4v").Replace("_swf", ".swf");
}
```

Comment: Hey, I would really love to use the ~/Media() syntax, but for some reason its not working for me. I have an ascx control that I load through the LoadUserControl function into my page. This is the code inside my repeater: `<img runat="server" src='<%#: "~/Media(" + Item.Image + ")" %>' alt="" />` It does not replace the string though with the actual media url. What could go wrong? Any ideas? I tried to leave out the runat=server, but that did not help.

Comment: Is it possible the URL replacement is applied before the databind of asp.net user controls?

Comment: True, C1 doesn't process result of user controls. I can see 2 possible solutions how to make it after the controls are rendered:
1) to write a control, which you can use to surround aspx controls with and which will be replacing the link in the inner content on Render event

Comment: 2) Write httpModule that would adding a response filter that would do the job.
a) Make a copy of Composite.Core.WebClient.HttpModules.AdministrativeResponseFilterHttpModule.
b) Change the condition on which the filter is added 
(httpContext.Handler != null && httpContext.Handler is Page && !httpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith(UrlUtils.AdminRootPath)
C) In Replacement stream use
public override string Process(string str) { return MediaUrlHelper.ChangeInternalMediaUrlsToPublic(str); }

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, but it's not exactly the shortest one:

```
MediaUrlHelper.GetUrl(MediaUrlHelper.GetFileFromQueryString(new NameValueCollection { {"id", myItem.Image} }))
```

I still hope someone comes up with a better solution, I will be happy to mark that one as the answer.

Comment: if you have a IMediaFile reference in your UserControl, cant you just pass that object into MediaUrlHelper.GetUrl(...) ??

Comment: Unfortunately I only have a string of the above form when I try to access the property if my page data folder in C#. In the same way as I only get a GUID when I try to access a page reference through the API.

Comment: true... i misunderstood and thought the image was a property on the UserControl. But why do you need the external url? Why not just write it like /media(mediaarchive:b5354eba-3f69-4885-9eba-74576dff372d) and let C1 expand the url for you at rendering?

Comment: Because I had no clue this syntax existed. Also it does not seem to work for my case, see comment to Dmitry's answer. Any help appreciated.